# Will there be performance effect with accessing variables with . parameter in c# unity3d

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, singleton

I am sorry if this question is being asked because this might be very simple or may be answer is obvious.

Hello in my game there are several line of code where every reference is got from a `GameManager.cs` which is singleton class.

For example:

```
public void someFunction()
{
    int a = GameManager.instance.healthController.something_1;
    GameManager.instance.healthController.updateHealth();
    GameManager.instance.healthController.updateArrows();
    GameManager.instance.healthController.updateRange();
}
```

Will above code has any effect on performance because I am using . to access variables and functions in several places.

Do I need to make any changes to improve coding style and performance if any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void someFunction()
{
    int a = GameManager.instance.healthController.something_1;
    GameManager.instance.healthController.updateHealth();
    GameManager.instance.healthController.updateArrows();
    GameManager.instance.healthController.updateRange();
}
```

could be rewritten as:

```
public void someFunction()
{
    var controller = GameManager.instance.healthController;
    int a = controller.something_1;
    controller.updateHealth();
    controller.updateArrows();
    controller.updateRange();
}
```

> Will above code has any effect on performance because I am using . to
>   access variables and functions in several places.

*Performance would be **slightly** better with my suggested version of the code (since it doesn't need to keep 'looking up' `instance` and `healthController`) - since [local variables are faster](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2968). In practice, though, it is **very** unlikely you would notice it.*

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to make any changes to improve coding style and performance
>   if any ?

**No**. Your code looks fine. If there needs to be one instance of it then do it this way. It will **not** affect the performance of your game.

What you should worry about *accessing another script* is *repeatedly* doing `GetComponent<HealthController>()` or `GameObject.FindXXX()` to find the script instead of caching them but you are not doing that, so its fine.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, i think that you can declare the variable 'a' out of the method, in class level. Then you avoid to create the variable everytime the method is called.

It is a good practice in game programming.

```
    private int a;
    public void someFunction()
    {
        a = GameManager.instance.healthController.something_1;
        GameManager.instance.healthController.updateHealth();
        GameManager.instance.healthController.updateArrows();
        GameManager.instance.healthController.updateRange();
    }
```